# Conditional expectations and random vectors.

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, conditional-expectation

Let $(\Omega, \sigma,P)$ a probability space and $Y$ a random variable on it, with $E|Y|<\infty$. Let $X_1,X_2$ random vectors with $\sigma(Y,X_1)$ independent of $\sigma(X_2)$. The problem is to prove that $$E(Y|X_1,X_2)=E(Y|X_1) \hspace{0.5cm} \text{almost surely}$$ It is enough to show that $$\int_D E(Y|X_1)dP=\int_DYdP \hspace{0.5cm} \forall D \in \sigma(X_1,X_2)$$ This equality is clearly true $\forall D \in \sigma(X_1)$, but what about the rest of the sets in $\sigma(X_1,X_2)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The next step is to show the identity when $D$ is of the form $D_1\cap D_2$, with $D_i\in\sigma(X_i)$. This can be done using independence. 
Then define $\mathcal P$ as the collection of  such sets. This is by definition stable under finite intersections, and conclude by [Dynkin's $\pi$-$\lambda$ theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynkin_system).